# Default file name in web browser

Tags: html

I'm designing a webpage that has an index.php file.  When I enter the url http://mywebpage.com, the index.php file is displayed as it should be, but the file name index.php is not displayed with the URL.  I'd like for it to have http://mywebpage.com/index.php.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

I have jQuery code that is responsible for highlighting the selected item in the navbar, but it is relying on the URL having the file name so that it can match the

Comment: There are several ways to do it: using `.htaccess`, entering the url with index.php at the end for the user, relocating using javascript's `window.location` object, and I may miss options.

Comment: So why not highlight whatever item in the navbar corresponds to the main page, whenever the filename is not there?  Web applications usually have a default page that is what the URL minus filename goes to.  Yours is defaulting to this page, have the jquery code also default to highlighting the corresponding navbar item.

Comment: That was one option that I was considering.  I just wanted to see if there was another way.

Comment: I think you will find it is the best option.  Default page -> default navbar item selected.

Comment: Conversely, you could modify your site so that index.php is not the default.  Make the default be something else... NotAPage.php.  Then have that reroute to index.php, or viceversa, leave index.php as the default, but have it not be a page.  Just have it reroute to MainPage.php.  And make the corresponding navbar item be linked to MainPage.php instead of index.php.

Answer (score 0):

if the file is named index.php/html will it be the main page but if its not the main page rename it to something like this index_1.php it will display mywebpage.com/index_1.php

Comment: Right.  That is working.  My issue is that index.php is not displaying in the webpage.  In my jQuery, it's comparing document.URL to the href of the nav items.  When the URL is not in the browser, it is not able to make a comparison.  Just wondering if there's a way to get the default webpage name to display, as in http://mywebsite.com/index.php when I enter http://mywebsite.com.